# Python Question Keeps on Getting Asked at the End of Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a game for my highschool project and am finding that the question "Take the sword? (yes/no): " is repeating at the end of my code, any answer to fixing this would be greatly appreciated, please note that I am just a beginner as well so a bit of a brief explanation may be required depending on how in depth the answer is. Thank you!

```
import time

def part5():
    print()
    print("As you venture across the path, you reach a crossroads...")
    print("You stop at the crossroads as you are met with 3 different paths...")
    print("Something shiny on the floor catches your eye...")
    print("You look down and it appears to be an old sword with a blue gem in its core...")
    time.sleep(1)
    answer = ""
    while answer.lower().strip() != "yes" and answer.lower().strip() != "no":
        answer = input("Take the sword? (yes/no): ")

        if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":
            item_count = 0
            item_count = item_count + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print()
            print("- Item added to your backpack -")
            print()
            print("You pick up the sword, now it's time to make your decision.")
            time.sleep(1)
            answer = ""
            while answer != "1" and answer != "2" and answer != "3":
                answer = input("What path will you choose? (1/2/3): ")

            battleAnswer = "2"

            if answer == battleAnswer:
                time.sleep(1)
                print()
                print("You head down path", answer + "...")
                print("After travelling for a while you find the path becoming darker...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("And darker...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Until...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("A tall dark monster appears before you...")
                print("Lets hope you know what you're doing!!")
                time.sleep(1)
                answer = ""
                while answer.lower().strip() != "yes" and answer.lower().strip() != "no":
                    answer = input("Fight the monster? (yes/no): ")

                    if answer == "yes" and item_count == 1:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print()
                        print("- Sword equipped from backpack -")
                        print()
                        print("You firmly grasp the sword in your hands...")
                        print("It fills you with determination as the monster charges towards you.")
                        print("You run up with your sword, challenging the monster...")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("Stomp, stomp, STOMP!!")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("SLICEEEEEEEE!")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("With a brave slash of your sword you slice through the monster...")
                        print("You face monster that had been cut in two...")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print("It looks you in the eye as it slowly fades away into dust.")
                        part6()
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print()
                        print("In a brave effort you attempt to sprint around the monster...")
                        print("You feel like the whole word is cheering you on, as if you're an olympic runner!")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("The monster looks down at you and stomps on you as if you are an ant.")
                        print("Wow, you suck at running.")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        restart()
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                print()
                print("You head down path", answer + "...")
                print("You feel as if someone is watching you as you wonder along the path.")
                print("Alas, this is your mind trying to trick you as it was a rabbit watching you.")
                part6()

        if answer.lower().strip() == "no":
            print()
            time.sleep(1)
            print("You think nothing of the sword and carry on to make your decision.")
            time.sleep(1)
            answer = ""
            while answer != "1" and answer != "2" and answer != "3":
                answer = input("What path will you choose? (1/2/3): ")

            battleAnswer = "2"

            if answer == battleAnswer:
                time.sleep(1)
                print()
                print("You head down path", answer + "...")
                print("After travelling for a while you find the path becoming darker...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("And darker...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Until...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("A tall dark monster appears before you...")
                print("Lets hope you know what you're doing!!")
                time.sleep(1)
                answer = ""
                while answer.lower().strip() != "yes" and answer.lower().strip() != "no":
                    answer = input("Fight the monster? (yes/no): ")

                    if answer == "yes":
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print()
                        print("You stand your ground against the monster and get your fists ready...")
                        print("You are brimming with confidence as you charge towards the monster...")
                        print("It attempts to attack you as you dodge many of its attacks...")
                        print("You punch it in the face as it stares at you...")
                        print("Your punch did nothing, so much for that confidence you had earlier.")
                        print("The monster slaps you to the ground, pathetic.")
                        restart()
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print()
                        print("In a brave effort you attempt to sprint around the monster...")
                        print("You feel like the whole word is cheering you on, as if you're an olympic runner!")
                        print("The monster looks down at you and stomps on you as if you are an ant.")
                        print("Wow, you suck at running.")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        restart()
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                print()
                print("You head down path", answer + "...")
                print("You feel as if someone is watching you as you wonder along the path.")
                print("Alas, this is your mind trying to trick you as there is nobody around.")
                part6()

    return


def part6():
    print()
    print("You successfully reach the end of the path and you are met with a large castle...")
    print("There is a stone bridge leading towards the entrance, under it is filled with lava.")
    
part5()
```

Comment: You are checking the variable `answer` in your while loop to see if `answer` is not *yes* and not *no*. Inside this same loop, you are assigning `answer` with values other than *yes* or *no*. This could be why you are re-entering the loop and the question is being printed again.

Comment: if we answer yes and then 2 it works fine. so the problem lies in your other path which is no  or after selecting yes , 1 or 3 . yes.no is repeating coz you have condition while . try to current that piece.

Comment: @bradmate, you can try and add more functions as there is a lot of repeating code. This would make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `answer` which is used to as the condition in while loop is not breaking out the loop since it has other values that *yes* or *no* at some instances and hence you are getting that question after you code executes.

For eg: if you initially choose *yes* and then choose *1*, `answer` variable will contain the value `1` and then you will call the method `part6()`. After the method `part6()` returns, it will continue to execute from the next line after the call to `part6()` was made. Since `answer` contains the value *1* and since this makes the while condition correct, your main while loop will continue.

To solve your problem, you can use another variable at places where it won't have values yes or no. This way you can be sure that after the function `part6()` returns, it will exit the loop.

Another way would be to use the `break` keyword to exit the while loop as soon as you return from `part6()` call and use `break` to exit out of all the while loops.

You can refactor your code by extracting certain portions of the code into different methods and changing the program flow a little (without changing the logic). From what I can see, rather than use `while` loop, you can just do a condition check using `if` after you've taken the input from the user.